# Перенос готового сайта с Магенто на Опенкарт

Tags: magento

Всем привет...
Прошу помочь...куплен сайт готовый на магенто как переделать его на опенкарт?какие идеи?
приблизительный срок за какое время возможно сделать одному?

Comment: Что значит переделать? Перенести контент? Дизайн? Добавить модули?

Comment: С Magento не работал, но, имея некоторый опыт разработки под Opencart и создания интернет-магазинов на его основе, полагаю, что нужны веские основания для переноса работающего магазина на эту платформу и хотя бы некоторые навыки работы с ней. Очень она, по-моему, своеобразна, и часто необходимо ковыряться в коде (впрочем, написанного с использованием паттерна MVC), чтобы что-то поменять. Имхо, разумеется.